# Build dropdown from database table names

Tags: mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms

I have this application where I want to deploy some web interface to a syslog server.

So the syslogserver does write his stuff into a mysql database. I already have build
some parts for the application except for this specific part where I want to build a dropdown select form, to select the hosttables inside the database.

Actually I am using flask, flask-sqlalchemy and wtforms. So I tried to implement this over the 'QuerySelectField', somehow I only get a dropdown with no table name entries shown.

I should mention that the tables inside the database itself are created on the fly. For my model I used the [automap_base()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html) Feature from sqlalchemy:

*model.py*

```
Base = automap_base()

engine = create_engine("mysql://sumuser:tehpass@127.0.0.1/syslog")

Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

session = Session(engine)
```

This is whats inside my forms:

*forms.py*

```
def factoryHelper():
    return  session.query("information_schema.tables.table_name from information_schema.tables where information_schema.tables.table_name like 'messages_hostname0'")



class HostSelectForm(Form):
    title = TextField('Fooblah')
    hostTables = QuerySelectField(query_factory=factoryHelper,allow_blank=True)
```

and this inside the views:

*views.py*

```
@app.route('/index/', defaults={'page':1})
@app.route('/index/page/<int:page>')
def index(page):
    form = HostSelectForm()
    count = session.execute("select host,facility,level,msg from messages_hostname0").rowcount
    pagination = Pagination(page, PER_PAGE, count)
    return render_template('index.html', pagination=pagination, form=form)
```

So is there anyway I can create a dropdown menu from dynamically created table names? Also if I use the automap feature? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow i managed to solve this issue with this in the model.py:

```
def reflectTables():
    for i in Base.classes.items():
        yield i[0]


def stripTables():
    tablelist = []
    datelist = []
    re0 = r"^(?P<prefix>[a-zA-Z]*)\_(?P<mid>[a-zA-Z,0-9]*)\_(?P<suffix>[0-9]*)"
    myre = re.compile(re0, re.MULTILINE)
    for x,table in enumerate(reflectTables()):
        striptablename = re.match(myre, table.strip("\n"))
        if striptablename:
            tablelist.append((x, striptablename.group(2)))
            datelist.append((x, striptablename.group(3)))
    return dicht(tablelist,datelist)
```

the forms.py:

```
AVAILABLE_CHOICES = stripTables()

class HostSelectForm(Form):
    tableSelect = SelectField('LogHost', choices=AVAILABLE_CHOICES, default=0)
```

and finnaly inside the views.py:

```
 if request.method == "GET":

        count = session.query("* from mytable_monitory_counts")
        items = session.execute("select * from mytable_%s_%s limit %s, %s" % \
                                (tableslector[int(request.values['tableSelect'])][1],\
                                 datelist[int(request.values['tableSelect'])][1], my_start_range, PER_PAGE)).fetchall()
        pagination = Pagination(page=page, total=count.count(), search=search, record_name='hosts')

        if not items and page != 1: 
            in_error()

        return render_template('index.html', pagination=pagination, form=form, items=items)
```